# Maven compile dependency error javax.mail missing

Tags: scala, maven, compilation, package, lift

I am following the instructions in the lift guide book for set up the basic hello world application (On windows 7 using cygwin)

After doing this to start

```
mvn archetype:generate -U -DarchetypeGroupId=net.liftweb \
-DarchetypeArtifactId=lift-archetype-blank -DarchetypeVersion=2.0 \
-DarchetypeRepository=http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases \
-DgroupId=demo.helloworld -DartifactId=helloworld \
-Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Then

```
cd helloworld
mvn jetty:run
```

I get the following error

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project helloworld: Could not resolve dependencies    for project demo.helloworld:helloworld:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [net.liftweb:lift-mapper:jar:2.0 (compile), javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5 (provided), junit:junit:jar:4.7 (test), org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:[6.1.6,7.0) (test), org.scala-lang:scala-compiler:jar:2.7.7 (test)]: No versions available for javax.mail:mail:jar:[1.4,1.4.3) within specified range -> [Help 1]

Before that there were two warning for checksum errors for the metadata.xml file. I put the checksum ignore in my pom file.

I downloaded the `mailx` API package from Oracle and put it in my classpath.  After trying various solutions found for similar sounding errors nothing seems to work. Can someone suggest something?

PS: I searched for two days for the answers and tried all the solutions that came up in various threads but found no answer in them.

Comment: visit this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965929/scala-lift-error-on-jettyrun-maven-eclipse. And could you please paste your pom.xml here to be reviewed once.

Answer (score 6):

You need to explicitly add `java.net` repository to your pom.xml. (Which is very weird)

```xml
  <repositories>
    <repository>
    <id>Java.Net</id>
    <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
    </repository>
    <!-- other repos -->
  </repositories>
```